# Android: download manager don't work with local url

Tags: android, video, download, localhost

I'm new in android and I'm trying to develop an app that shows videos and download it using download manager
but I have 2 problem

1st- when I trying to download video from my local server **(WAMP server)** it didn't download but if i put link from internet it's work

2nd- the download arrow doesn't appear and I don't way

this is my download method

```
 public void downloadFileFromUrl(String url, String fileName) {

        String filePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "BlueNet";

        try {

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4");
            //Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.5:8080/BlueNet_NMC/video_share/blue_elephant.mp4");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/BlueNet",fileName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        long id= downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(this, fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        catch (Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and I already give this permissions to my manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

so any help please..

Comment: Where is your app running?

Comment: You are not checking if dir BlueNet exists.

Comment: I running it on my mobile and make my laptop as server, its connected ok because i can watch the video but can' download it.... and about checking the dir .. download manager is already check from dir if exists or not